# How to check if a URL contains a date in PHP

Tags: php, validation, url

I want to build an automated function to automatically upload reports from a URL at end of the day if found on that URL. My question is the URL keeps changing daily with a date. How can I obtain whether the URL has a date? Here I am pasting the url from which i need to extract data

www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/EQ140316_CSV.ZIP

So the string after "Equity/" needs to be validated as it contains the date. How to build a function in php fro that..
It will be a great help. Thanks in advance

here is the code that I am following,

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/EQ140316_CSV.ZIP';
if ( preg_match("/\/EQ\d{6}_CSV\.ZIP/", $url, $matches)) {
$path = '/upload/';

$headers = getHeaders($url);

if ($headers['http_code'] === 200 and $headers['download_content_length'] < 1024*1024) {
  if (download($url, $path)){
    echo 'Download complete!'; 
  }
}
}


/**
 * Get Headers function
 * @param str #url
 * @return array
 */
function getHeaders($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3 );
  curl_exec( $ch );
  $headers = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  return $headers;

}

 /**
 * Download
 * @param str $url, $path
 * @return bool || void
 */
function download($url, $path)
{
  # open file to write
  $fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
  # start curl
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  # set return transfer to false
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
  # increase timeout to download big file
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 );
  # write data to local file
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );
  # execute curl
  curl_exec( $ch );
  # close curl
  curl_close( $ch );
  # close local file
  fclose( $fp );

  if (filesize($path) > 0) 
      return true;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function containsDate($url){
   preg_match("/\/EQ\d{6}_CSV\.ZIP/", $url, $matches);
   return !empty($matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the effort Mu'men Yassin. But my last doubt stays the same.. what $url must hold.. the whole url or some part of it

Comment: The url string that you want to check if it contains the date, i mean something like:
    www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/EQ140316_CSV.ZIP

Comment: Thanks Mu'men Yassin. can you help me with obtaining this CSV file and saving it to server automatically? Cron is an option but the script that cron run is what i want.. I had been googling around alot burt no success

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match:

```
preg_match('/EQ([0-9]+)_/'), $url, $matches);

$date = $matches[1];
```

To run a cron to do that daily you simply need to type in `crontab -e` on the shell.

Here is a sample cronline for a daily run at 4am:

```
    0 4 * * * php /home/user/website/bin/your_script.php

# leave an empty line on the bottom of the crontab
```

Find help here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Comment: A big thanks KiwiJuicer. I have a doubt, why are we taking $date here and $url must contain what part of the URL??

Comment: It's just naming man, $url = 'www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/EQ140316_CSV.ZIP' and $date will contain 140316

Comment: I want to download "Bhavcopy.cvs" file form "nseindia.com" on everyday at 5 pm.

So, I want php code that automatic download this file from "nse" website... here is my code thats not working.. let me know if i am wrong

Comment: Thanks KIwiJuicer can you help me with obtaining this CSV file and saving it to server automatically? Cron is an option but the script that cron run is what i want.. I had been googling around alot burt no success. Guidance will be highly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Please open a new question and give something you have tried to work with

Comment: But your question now is not realeted to that one

Comment: actualy it is related. I am working on automated file upload at a particular time and still found no luck.. my bprev question was the part of it :(

Comment: I just posted the code. Please check and let me know what more has to be done.. executing this gives a blank page and i can't make out whats going wrong

Comment: you can provide if you have something better and executable